# Nodejs Security Issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, security, ejs

I found a little security issue on my code! Here's how it works: The user requests some data from the server, the server then finds them in the database, makes an array and sends it to the client. There, the html has a function to render the array in a particular template. The thing is: if someone types the name of the array in the developer's console, he can see all the data in it, including emails, phone numbers, addresses and so on! My question is: do I have to remove the sensitive data from the array before sending it to the client, or render the html before hand and then send it to them (and if I have it's the second one, how do I do it?). That's my problem. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: You should remove sensitive data from the array you're sending, it's simpler, you won't have to change anything client side.

Comment: Yes, you have to remove sensitive data on the server before you return the response to the client.  The browser client code is NEVER a secure environment so you never send it anything that is not allowed to be seen.  We can only help you do that if you show the relevant server-side code.

Comment: Whatever you send from server/database need to have some access control logic. If client is making request then such requests have to be validated for authenticity. If request from client is authentic then and only then you are sending information. Indeed it is true that sensitive information should never be sent to client. All the processing of such information should ever happen on server level. Client logic of your code is always exposed so abstract sensitive logic from client and do it on server.

Comment: UPDATE: I actually tried to remove the sensitive data from the array, but splice() starded doing some funky stuff! Here's the code, for some reason splice() doesn't seem to work. for(var a = 0; a < userArray.length; a++){ userArray[0].userData.username.splice(0, 1); }; but it will work with some custom made arrays! (where it says userArray[0] I also tried userArray[a] but it still won't work)

Comment: Multi-line code in comments is not readable.  You can use the "edit" link below your question to add relevant code to your question, format it appropriately and then address a comment to whomever you most want to know it is now there.  In your case, you need to show what the format of the data is originally and what you want it to look like after it's been modified.  Probably what you want to do is to build a new array with only the right data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Only send what you need to.

Not only is it good for data protection purposes, but if you're sending data that isn't meant to be used, you're wasting bandwidth!